# Type mismatch error 13 when passing a range to a function in Excel VBA 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a Type Mismatch error 13 on the line highlighted below, although I suspect I will be getting this error with all the ranges.

```
Function Xtreme(Window_ID As Range, WIDTH As Range, HEIGHT As Range, xlb As Range, ylb As Range, Coord_Opt As Integer)

Dim iHOT_SURF(100) As Single
Dim iCOLD_SURF(100) As Single
Dim iHOT_NUM As Single


Dim x_L(100) As Single
Dim x_R(100) As Single
Dim x_C(100) As Single

For i = 1 To iHOT_NUM
    **x_L(i) = WorksheetFunction.Index(xlb, i)**
```

This is how I'm calling the function (to test):

```
Sub testmy()
Dim x As Variant
x = Xtreme(Sheets("Groupwise Data").Range("A5:A29"), Sheets("Groupwise Data").Range("B5:B29"), Sheets("Groupwise Data").Range("C5:C29"), Sheets("Groupwise Data").Range("E5:E29"), Sheets("Groupwise Data").Range("F5:F29"), 1)
End Sub
```

The ranges contain either values or are Empty (Using `IFERROR(Value, "")` )

Can someone please tell me how to get this function to work correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: What is this function supposed to do?

Comment: It calculates a flux density. So here is the thing: if I use this function on the same sheet where the data tables are located e.g `Xtreme($A$5:$A$29,$B$5:$B29,$C$5:$C$29,$D$5:$D$29,$E$5:$E$29,1)` it works fine. It has something to do with the way values are being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x_L(i) = CSng(WorksheetFunction.Index(xlb, i))
```

Or

```
x_L(i) = CSng(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(xlb, i))
```

Give that WorksheetFunction returns a Variant. ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197581.aspx

Comment: The issue is with the range not the function. I can't even `Debug.Print xlb` in first line of the function.

Comment: @MuneebM perhaps try passing the param `ByRef`?

Comment: @MuneebM what is the output from `Debug.Print Sheets("Groupwise Data").Range("E5:E29")`

Comment: @MuneebM There's your problem :) If you need help continuing please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with the range. Cells E5,E6 and E7 have numerical values while rest of them are empty. So what could be the issue?

Comment: @MuneebM Most likely you need `.Value` on the end.

Comment: You cannot ever debug.print a multi-cell range. if the cell formula returns "" you can't assign directly to an element of an array declared as Single (Double would be better, fyi, as that's what excel uses). you might add a test for "" or Isnumeric or use a Double array and Val on the result of the Index

Comment: @JosieP It works fine if I use this function on the same sheet where the data set is located. Please see my comment to the original post.

Comment: your example is calling from a sub so I don't follow? either way my comment stands-if a cell has "" from a formula you _will_ get a type mismatch